# Parsing Database Table name using Regex

Tags: python, sql, regex, parsing

I have data that contain database table name.

with code like this:

```
for l,col in enumerate(data):
#print(data[l][1])
a = data[l][1]
parse = extract_tables(a)
print(parse)
```

the data is like this:

```
['public.actor']
['public.film']
['film']
['film', 'rental', 'inventory']
['inventory i', 'customer c', 'film f', 'rental r']
['customer as c', 'rental as r']
```

i want it to be like this:

```
['actor']
['film']
['film']
['film', 'rental', 'inventory']
['inventory', 'customer', 'film', 'rental']
['customer', 'rental']
```

i want to remove the "public", "as" and also the alias like "c", "f", and "r", so that i only get the original name table from the data. (like actor, film, rental).
i work in python. please help me. thank you

Comment: Please correct your indention.

Answer (score 0):

If your only cases are to remove `public.` and `as x` from your inputs, you can use

```
re.sub("(public\.|\sas.+)", "", input_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean(string):
    p = string.split()
    if len(p) == 1:
        return p[0].split('.')[-1]
    else:
        return p[0]
```

Comment: Hello. You also need to add some explanation with your answer. You can write about what mistake OP was making or what he/she missed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the set of expected possible database table names?  Seems like you would or would be able to query it from the database.  If so:

```
database_tables = ['actor', 'film', 'rental', 'inventory', 'customer']
results = []
for db_list in data:
    db_list = [db for db in database_tables if db in ''.join(db_list)]
    results.append(db_list)
```

If you don't then your solution will only be as good as the predictability of the incoming data to clean.  With the set you have:

```
result = []
for db_list in data:
    db_list = [db.split('public.')[0] for db in db_list]
    db_list = [db.split(' ')[0] for db in db_list]
    result.append(db_list)
```